# issue with IHS load balancer

Tags: websphere, websphere-8

I am wokring on websphere clusering (ND 8.5.5), and i want to use IHS (IBM HTTP SERVER) version 8.5.5 as load balancer but I can't find the download link of this version.

Do you guys have any idea where can i find it ?

Answer (score 0):

IBM HTTP Server is a software that is included with the WAS license and can be downloaded in the same place as where you would get the installation files for your WAS server.

If you have Passport advantage with you WAS server you can download the IBM HTTP server from there as well. Note though that downloading software may be limited to only some users at your company. If so you need to contact your technical administrator at your company to either give you that access or let you know who can help you.

I have also found download links att IBMs [IBM HTTP Server product page](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/http-servers), but I have not gone all the way to test the download.

Comment: I am using network deployment 8.5.5 and cant find ihs that is applicable withat all

Comment: IHS is available at passport advantage so this is still applicable. Now I saw in Gas solution that he described exactly what files it is that you need.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download it form Passport advantage. It will be on set of files that have 'Supplement' in the file description. Download will contain IBM HTTP Server and WebSphere Plugin (installed via WebSphere Customization Toolkit). You will need to install both to be able to distribute workload to your cluster.

As far as I know IHS download from product page doesn't contain WCT and Plugin.

See also:
[Installing IBM HTTP Server](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/tins_webserver.html?lang=en)
[Installing and configuring web server plug-ins](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/tins_webplugins.html?lang=en)

**UPDATE**
The Network deployment media contains IHS and plugin. Download the following files form Passport Advantage:

```
IBM WebSphere Application Server V8.5.5 Supplements (1 of 3) for Multiplatform Multilingual (CIK1VML)
IBM WebSphere Application Server V8.5.5 Supplements (2 of 3) for Multiplatform Multilingual (CIK1WML)  
IBM WebSphere Application Server V8.5.5 Supplements (3 of 3) for Multiplatform Multilingual (CIK1XML )
```

Comment: but I have network deployment edition websphere, so should i change it to supplement ( dont know the edition of websphere application server inside it !

Comment: Thaaaanks so much Gas, so i will find ND , IHS and plugins from the upper download links,,,, thank you so much :D